# How to join tables in a group/users relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The problem:
Select all groups where a user with `id = 1` is an administrator and all groups to which the same user belongs without including duplicates. You can be a group administrator without belonging to it.

The schema:

```
users table
id, name

groups table
id, name, admin_id (user_id)

group_members table
group_id, member_id
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT groups.name as group_name,
users.id as user_id,
users.name as user_name
FROM groups
INNER JOIN users ON groups.admin_id = users.id and users.id=1
LEFT JOIN group_members ON group_members.group_id = groups.id
LEFT JOIN users as users2 on group_members.member_id = users2.id and users2.id=1;
```

Current results

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a3158/26

**Update 1**
edited to indicate that the query is for a single user with id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Select all groups where a user with `id = 1` is an administrator and all groups to which the same user belongs without including duplicates

Two solutions:

```
SELECT g.id AS group_id, g.name AS group_name
FROM   groups g
WHERE (g.admin_id = 1
OR     EXISTS (
        SELECT FROM group_members gm
        WHERE gm.group_id = g.id
        AND   gm.member_id = 1));
```

Or:

```
SELECT id AS group_id, name AS group_name
FROM   groups
WHERE  admin_id = 1

UNION
SELECT g.id, g.name
FROM   group_members gm
JOIN   groups        g ON g.id = gm.group_id
WHERE  gm.member_id = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/563da/10 building on yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct member_id, group_id from group_members 
where member_id in(select admin_id from groups) 
order by member_id, group_id
```

I don't think a join is strictly necessary to achieve the desired [result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a3158/38)...

Here it is with [joins](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a3158/43) to pull in the user/group names.

```
select distinct m.member_id, u.name, m.group_id, g.name 
from group_members m
left join users u
on member_id = u.id
left join groups g
on group_id = g.id
where m.member_id in(select admin_id from groups) 
order by member_id, group_id
```

Comment: This is working pretty well, but seems to fail when filtering for a single user (question updated to reflect this)

Comment: Then you would just modify the `in` part of the `where` clause for the id you wanted - perhaps using the simplified form of `=`.